# GLM anidado en R

Tags: r, variables, glm

estoy intentando realizar un estudio sobre invertebrados en diferentes tipos de olivares. Mi duda es la siguiente: quiero saber si alguna especie de invertebrado se asocia significativamente a alguno de los olivares (son tres tipos: superintensivo, convencional y ecológico). Para ello, he intentado elaborar un GLM anidado, con Abundancia de cada especie (nº de individuos) como variable respuesta, y el Muestreo (se hicieron 3: abril, mayo y junio), Manejo (tipo de olivar), y Especies (nombre de cada especie) como factores. Además, he intentado que Especies vaya anidada dentro de Muestreo, anidado a su vez dentro de Manejo.
El resultado que he obtenido lo he traducido como que, donde los valores de p son menores de 0,05, significa que esa especie está asociada a ese olivar.

Los datos analizados siguen el siguiente formato:

| Especies | Manejo | Muestreo | Abundancia |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Especie 1 | Superin | Muestreo1 | 70 |
| Especie 1 | Superin | Muestreo2 | 50 |
| Especie 1 | Superin | Muestreo3 | 5 |
| Especie 1 | Convenc | Muestreo1 | 40 |
| Especie 1 | Convenc | Muestreo2 | 34 |
| Especie 1 | Convenc | Muestreo3 | 12 |
| Especie 1 | Ecologi | Muestreo1 | 20 |
| Especie 1 | Ecologi | Muestreo2 | 6 |
| Especie 1 | Ecologi | Muestreo3 | 4 |
| Especie 2... |  |  |  |

El script de R que he utilizado es el siguiente:

```
summary(glm(Abundancia ~ Muestreo+Manejo+ï..Especies%in%Muestreo%in%Manejo,data=bioin,family=poisson(link="log")))
```

Me gustaría saber si el modelo que he hecho sería correcto para responder a la pregunta que me hago (cuáles son las especies que se asocian a los olivares).

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola antalfmor y bienvendo/a a SO en español. No tengo una respuesta, pero sí un par de preguntas quizás te ayuden a encontrar la respuesta. Si tu pregunta pasa por la asociación entre especie y manejo y el muestreo es una "molestia" que tienes que controlar 1) ¿por qué incluyes al muestro en las interacciones/anidado? Lo podrías dejar como término independiente solamente, para que las demás pendientes se estimen en cada media de muestreo.  Si el manejo solo te interesa en su relación con las especies 2) ¿Por qué incluyes a manejo como término independiente y no solamente en la interacción?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes explorar un modelo mixto (o multinivel) para lo que estás buscando.

Hay varios paquetes en R que puedes usar para eso.

El paquete `lme4` es bastante usado. La fórmula seria:

```r
library(lme4)

summary(fm1 <- glmer(Abundancia ~ Manejo + Especies + (1 | Muestreo),
                     data = bioin,
                     family = "poisson"))
```

Ese modelo aplicaría para anidar las observaciones por muestreo y por ende controlar para el efecto de medidas seudoreplicadas.

Puedes ajustar la fórmula, dependiendo de tus hipótesis y los grados de libertad apropiados para la colecta que realizaste.

La variable que está agrupando (efecto aleatorio) puede ser explorada con mayor profundidad usando el paquete `lme4`.

Puedes leer más sobre modelos mixtos en diferentes referencias. El siguiente libro es una buena referencia:

Andrew Gelman and Jennifer Hill: Data analysis using regression and multilevel/hierarchical models

Puedes mirar el siguiente link sobre el paquete `lme4`:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/index.html